# SQL-server, largest value for numeric(16, 8)?

Tags: sql-server, numeric, sqldatatypes

Just got badly bitten by MS SQL when tried to save a large value `11545545645.00` into a column with type `numeric(16, 8)`.

Is there a way to figure out the max value such a numeric column can have based on its precision and scale?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The maximum total number of decimal digits that can be stored, both to
>   the left and to the right of the decimal point. The precision must be
>   a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38.
>   [decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

So in your case numeric(16, 8) you have 8 (`16 - 8`) digits left before the decimal point